# Thinkpad L450 intel wifi chipset regularly needs to be "restarted" through windows diagnostics tool

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, wifi-driver

The name of the device is 2x2 11bgn Wireless LAN M.2 Adapter

I'm not sure if it's possible to find a better driver/firmware for it.

It never did this before, I guess wifi chips can age or suffer from heat? It happens somewhat randomly during the day, sometime every 2 or 3 days, it's a little hard to say.

I got an ETL file that says

```
AutoConfig Helper Class repair status 1 HRESULT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had that problem before with my laptop (which is coincidentally a ThinkPad as well) with an Intel WiFI card. However, the issue went away when I replaced my ISP-supplied router with a different one along with a wireless access point. This does not mean you have to do that but suggests that the problem may be on the other end of the wifi connection.

So, see if it happens when connected to another wifi network.

If it does not happen elsewhere, try adjusting which wifi channels your router/wap is using. You can see which channels are congested using [InSSIDer or similar (including some apps for your phone)](https://alternativeto.net/software/inssider/).

If it does happen with other wifi connections, you can look at adjusting the power-saving setting in Power Options.

[image: wifi power options]

There are also some drive options for the Intel wireless card in Device Manager which you can try changing, but those depend on what driver and I am not using Windows at the moment, so I can't say much more about that.

I'm sure I have used all these methods over the years, with eventual success.